# Problems with Streaming Videos Darwin Streaming Server

Tags: video-streaming, media, darwin

I am having problems with Darwin streaming server. I have successfully installed it and I have also successfully used it to stream the compatible samples to my android phone. I was very happy at this point. I then took some of my personal videos and encoded them into a similar format and placed them in the same folder. When I requested these new videos from my rtsp client I could not view them. I then tired the same thing with VLC and got the same result. After viewing the TCP/RTSP packets on wireshark it seems that for both players I was getting a RTSP 404 error relating to file or service not available. Have I missed something and have to update a file somewhere with my new files because the server is acting as if it is unaware of these new videos. Could someone who uses Darwin streaming server (on windows) please tell me what I am doing wrong as I cannot find a decent  guide for windows users any where on the internet. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I had to install active perl to access the web interface and correctly set up the media folder. Also all media files need to be hinted  before streaming using DSS, so I used mp4box to hint the tracks. Once these steps had been followed and my new media files were placed in the correct folder, I could finally stream the media to my Android phone.